# Question on Speed and Distance

Tags: algebra-precalculus, recreational-mathematics, puzzle

X, Y and Z move along a circular path of length 1.2 km with speeds of 6 km/h, 8 km/h and 9 km/h respectively. X and Y move in the same direction but Z moves in opposite direction. If they all start at the same time and from same place, how many times will X and Z meet anywhere on the path by the time X and Y meet for the first time anywhere on the path ? I was getting the answer as 7 times but the correct answer is 8. Am I wrong ? Can someone explain ?

Comment: How did you get 7?

Comment: by using relative speed, Y wud meet X after 1.2/2 = 0.6h. In this time, X and Z would meet 1.2/15 = 7.5 times .. since number should be natural, it should be less than 7.5. Thus, required answer should be 7. Am I going wrong somewhere ?

Comment: It should be X and Z meet 0.6*15/1.2=7.5 times, but that supports your answer

Answer (score 0):

I think it is a [fencepost error](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fencepost_error#Fencepost_error).  X and Z meet once at the start, after zero hours, and the seven more you calculated.

Comment: But then, the same should hold for X and Y as the first time they meet is at the starting point.

Comment: That is true.  I can't find another answer.  Maybe the book is wrong.